# Windows disk space not increasing with Hyper-V increase

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, virtual-disk

I first created a VM with 10 GB hard disk space but when Windows booted, there was only 69 MB free. Therefore, I created another disk (red-marked in image) but selected "Copy contents from existing disk". This new disk I created of 50 GB space but when Windows boots, it is showing old disk space only.

[image]

#### Old disk space

[image]

Even in the VM settings, it is pointing to red-marked big disk:

[image]

Comment: Check / Show Disk Management.

Comment: @John Ya... That is the last option. Will waste time again.

Comment: Just go into Windows OS and then go to Disk Management. From there it should allow you to expand/extent any unallocated space to the existing disk partition at the Window's OS level. At the Hyper-V level, it's been expanded, but at the Windows level it has not, so you should see it as unallocated space at the OS level which you should be able to extend over to the Windows "C" drive. You should not have to create a new VM, just give it hypervisor space and then tell Windows to allocate it so it can start using it. This is usually very simple and easy to complete.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Thanks. I updated OP with local machine Disk Management image but you meant VM disk management image. Performed that and it fixed the space issue. Please post as answer so that I can mark it solved.

Comment: @RPK - What you have provided isn't Disk Management but File Explorer.

Comment: @Ramhound I provided wrong Disk Management screenshot. Anyways I deleted it.

Comment: @RPK [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7yms.png) is File Explorer not Disk Mangement.

Comment: The screen shot of disk management wasn't needed anyway and the ones you provided plus what you wrote up above the screen shots was enough to figure out what you had going on. This is a common problem people run into and I understood just fine what you had going on with what you provided so I'm glad you got it working. I don't understand the downvote or the close votes on this question, shake the haters off! You explained what you did and what you had going on, so it was really simple to understand your problem without a lot more being needed from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the Hyper-V level, it's been expanded, but at the Windows OS level it has not. You should see available unallocated space at the Windows OS level via `diskmgmt.msc`. This is the space available to extend the Windows "C" drive from its perspective on a particular disk.

It really should just be a matter of giving the hypervisor VM disk additional space and then tell Windows to allocate it so it can start using it. This is usually very simple and easy to complete.

> ## Solution
>
> 1. Go into Windows OS and then go to Disk Management via `diskmgmt.msc`.
> 2. Select the disk and right click on the partition which you want to expand its space.
> 3. Select `Extend Volume` and extend that over into whatever unallocated space it shows  available.